# ssh connection time out after reboot GCE instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

Can anyone tell me why after reboot a Google Compute Engine instance i get a ssh connection time out. I reboot the instance by sudo reboot and by Google Compute Engine Console and both do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Brian Dorsey, E. Anderson and vgt for answering my question. The problem was other. Every time that i reseted the connection previously i up an ethernet bridge with the brigde-util utility between the "eth0" inferface and a new brigde interface called "br0". After reset the instance by `sudo reboot` or by GCE Console, ssh connection stopped working.

But if i don't up the ethernet bridge the instance restart ok by both methods.

Comment: Hey there. Good that you found your solution. Can you please detail the steps that you took to resolve your issue. I am facing the same problem and I don't know how to replicate what you did.

Answer (score 5):

When the OS shuts down to reboot, all network connections are closed, including SSH connections. From the client side, this can look like a connection time out.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `gcutil resetinstance`, it does the same thing as pushing the power button on a physical host.  This is different from e.g. `sudo reboot`, because the former does not give the operating system a chance to perform any shutdown (like closing open sockets, flushing buffers, etc), while the latter does an orderly shutdown.

You should probably prefer logging in to the instance to do a reboot rather than using `gcutil resetinstance` if the host is still ssh-able; `resetinstance` (or the "Reboot Instance" button in the GUI) is a hard reset, which allows you to recover from a kernel crash or SSH failing.

In more detail:

During OS-initiated reboot (like `sudo reboot`), the operating system performs a number of cleanup steps and then moves to runlevel 6 (reboot).  This causes all the scripts in `/etc/init.d` to be run and then a graceful shutdown.  During a graceful shutdown, `sshd` will be killed; `sshd` could catch the kill signal to close all of its open sockets.  Closing the socket will cause a `FIN` TCP packet to be sent, starting an orderly TCP teardown ("Connection closed" message in your ssh client).  Alternatively, if `sshd` simply exits, the kernel sends a `RST` (reset) packet on all open TCP sockets, which will cause a "Connection reset" message on your ssh client.  Once all the processes have been shut down, the kernel will make sure that all dirty pages in the page cache are flushed to disk, then execute one of two or three mechanisms to trigger a BIOS reboot.  (ACPI, keyboard controller, or triple-fault.)

When triggering an external reset (e.g. via the `resetinstance` API call or GUI), the VM will go immediately to the last step, and the operating system won't have a chance to do any of the graceful shutdown steps above.  This means your ssh client won't receive a `FIN` or `RST` packet like above, and will only notice the connection closed when the remote server stops responding. ("Connection timed out")

Answer (score 0):

Slightly orthogonal to Brian's answer. To gracefully reboot a GCE VM you can use:

```
gcutil resetinstance <instancename>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your instance image is CentOS, try to remove selinux.

```
sudo yum remove selinux*
```